# Uploading large files to Azure fileshare

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, fileshare

I am able to upload small files to fileshare using below code but large files are not getting transferred. There are methods like `blob.PutBlock` available to upload files to Blob, but can't find anything for fileshare. Can you please guide me?

```
StorageCredentials cred = new StorageCredentials("SASToken");
CloudFileClient fClient = new CloudFileClient(new Uri(FileShareUrl)), cred);

CloudFileShare fshare = fileClient.GetShareReference("FileShareName");
CloudFileDirectory root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference("Folder/subfolder");

var cloudFile = dir.GetFileReference(fileName);
await cloudFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(incomingBlob).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload the file from a website to the storage account? Then you are probably hitting the RequestSizeLimit. Add this right before your Funktion: [RequestSizeLimit(20971520000)]

Comment: I am sending from a blob from one storage account to a fileshare in another account using blob trigger.

Comment: You can consider Alex's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of streaming large files through your Azure Function, you should use the [DataMovement library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/) to copy the files directly from blob storage to your target file share.

The `TransferManager` class has a corresponding `CopyAsync` method to [copy files from blob to file share](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-net-data-movement/html/dfca512a-d4f0-4df3-d2ae-37045ab7cfa8.htm).

Here are [some samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library) to get you started with the library, you just need to adjust it to file share instead of blobs.